# Sudoku generation doesn't finish

Tags: c#

Heyho,

i got problems with my sudoku generator. First of all I generate some numbers between 1 and 9 and put them (according to the sudoku rules) into my game. After that I solve it using my second algorithm, but there's a problem with. It stops solving in the middle of the sudoku and says that there isn't a single solution for it, even if this sudoku has around 200 solutions.

```
private void generateSudoku()
{
//iSeed für den Random-Generator
iSeed = seeder.Next();
rnd = new Random(iSeed);

for(int i = 0; i < FIELDSIZE; i++)
{
    iContent[i] = 0;
    bEditable[i] = true;
}

switch(iDifficulty)
{
    case 0:  iNumbers = rnd.Next(30, 35);
        break;
    case 1:  iNumbers = rnd.Next(24, 29);
        break;
    case 2:  iNumbers = rnd.Next(18, 23);
        break;
    default: iNumbers = rnd.Next(24, 29);
        break;
}

for(int i = 0; i <= iNumbers; i++)
{
    int iValue = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    int iRow = rnd.Next(0, ROWSIZE);
    int iCol = rnd.Next(0, ROWSIZE);

    if(check(iRow, iCol, iValue) == 0)
    {
        iIndex = (ROWSIZE*iRow+iCol);
        iContent[iIndex] = iValue;
        bEditable[iIndex] = false;
    }else
    {
        i--;
    }
}

iSolutionCounter = 0;
solveSudoku(0);

Console.WriteLine("Solutions: " + iSolutionCounter);

if(iSolutionCounter != 1)
{
    //generateSudoku();
    //return;
}

for(int i = 0; i < FIELDSIZE; i++)
{
    if(bEditable[i] == true)
    {
        iSolution[i] = iContent[i];
        //iContent[i] = 0;
    }else
    {
        iSolution[i] = iContent[i];
    }
}
```

}

- FIELDSIZE = 81;    The number of fields in complete sudoku (9x9)
- ROWSIZE = 9;       The number of fields in a single row or column (9)
- iNumbers           The amount of random generated startnumbers

And the solveSudoku(), which should solve the sudoku and sum up all solutions (but fails)

```
private bool solveSudoku(int iPos)
{
    int iCol = (iPos % ROWSIZE);
    int iRow = (int)(iPos / ROWSIZE);

    if(iPos >= FIELDSIZE)
    {
        iSolutionCounter++;
        return false;
    }

    if(iContent[iPos] >= 1)
    {
        return solveSudoku(iPos + 1);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= ROWSIZE; i++) 
    {
        if(check(iRow, iCol, i) == 0) 
        {
            iContent[iPos] = i;
            if(solveSudoku(iPos + 1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

That's what I mean (grey numbers are the ones, which are available at start, so you (or my algorithm) can't edit them:

[image: Sudoku Problem]

Comment: I'm using backtracking here. So the algorithm tries to fill in a 1, if that fits it goes to the next field and try to put in 1, 2, 3... etc. if no number fit, it goes back to the 1 it has already put in and put in a 2, then it goes to the next field again, and so on... -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking#Examples

Comment: The sudoku itself is possible

http://www.surfpoeten.de/sudoku?s0=4&s1=&s2=&s3=&s4=&s5=5&s6=&s7=&s8=7&s9=&s10=&s11=5&s12=&s13=&s14=&s15=9&s16=2&s17=6&s18=&s19=&s20=&s21=1&s22=&s23=&s24=4&s25=&s26=3&s27=1&s28=&s29=&s30=3&s31=&s32=&s33=2&s34=&s35=4&s36=&s37=4&s38=&s39=&s40=&s41=&s42=&s43=6&s44=9&s45=&s46=5&s47=&s48=&s49=&s50=&s51=&s52=8&s53=&s54=5&s55=&s56=&s57=&s58=&s59=7&s60=&s61=&s62=&s63=&s64=&s65=&s66=&s67=&s68=&s69=&s70=9&s71=&s72=7&s73=&s74=&s75=&s76=6&s77=&s78=&s79=&s80=&max=3&solve=L%C3%B6sung%28en%29+suchen&id=9#answer

Comment: Sudokus are generally generated from a filled in sudoku and erasing numbers that the algorithm can prove is not "crucial".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should reassign 0 to the position at the end of the loop.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= ROWSIZE; i++) 
{
    if(check(iRow, iCol, i) == 0) 
    {
        iContent[iPos] = i;
        if(solveSudoku(iPos + 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
iContent[iPos] = 0;
return false;
```

Otherwise the solver will think that the position is filled in when it's backtracking.

---

Your simple solver is a bit too simple for the job to be efficient. If the first guess it makes is wrong then it can take a long time for it to discover that and retry.

Sudoku solving is a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) so take some lessons out of the methods for resolving those. I suggest doing some kind of constraint propagation before going to guess.

Also instead of guessing in a fixed pattern you can guess a number in the square with the least number of options left. If that square has no options left then there is no solution.

Comment: reassigning the 0 fixed the problem, thanks.